# Why do my Scrapy rules (LinkExtractor) don't work?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my first question ever in Stack Overflow. I started using Python to **scrape** data at work and I have been using Scrapy to achieve these tasks. I tried setting up a scraper for a government website and I do not have an output. Initially I set three rules in my rules variable, but my json file would come up empty. The code is fine but I do not know what is going wrong. Thank you for any insight that you are able to share. Have a good day.

````
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
class DirSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'di7'
    allowed_domains = ['transparencia.gob.sv']
    start_urls = ['https://www.transparencia.gob.sv/categories/2']
    

rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=".filtrable a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css="a:nth-of-type(19)"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        
        items = {}
        
        css_selector = response.css(".spaced .align-justify")
        
        for bureaucrat in css_selector:
            name = bureaucrat.css(".medium-11 a::text").extract_first()
            charge = bureaucrat.css(".medium-12::text").extract_first()
            status = bureaucrat.css(".medium-11 .text-mutted::text").extract_first()
            institution = response.css("small::text").extract()
            
            items['name'] = name
            items['charge'] = charge
            items['status'] = status
            items['institution'] = institution
            
            yield(items)```
````

Comment: Do you have `parse_item` callback?

Comment: Yes, I put it in my rules code

Comment: I mean did you define `parse_item` like you defined `parse`?

Comment: No I did not. Where should I define it? In the items.py file or should I write it as a function in this file? I basically applied the same template of this spider from a udemy course

Comment: You were right on the money!! Thank you man!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename your `parse` function into `parse_item`:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    items = {}

    css_selector = response.css(".spaced .align-justify")

    for bureaucrat in css_selector:
        name = bureaucrat.css(".medium-11 a::text").extract_first()
        charge = bureaucrat.css(".medium-12::text").extract_first()
        status = bureaucrat.css(".medium-11 .text-mutted::text").extract_first()
        institution = response.css("small::text").extract()

        items['name'] = name
        items['charge'] = charge
        items['status'] = status
        items['institution'] = institution

        yield(items)
```